# call a base class method using a derived class object outside the derived class

Tags: python, inheritance, super

i have seen many posts that describe how to call base class function is called inside a derived class function using the super keyword.I want to call a base class overloaded function globally using a derived class object.

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=45
    def fun(self):
        print "fun in base class"
class b(a):
    def __init__(self):
        self.y=98           
    def fun(self):
        print "fun in derived class"
objb=b()
objb.fun()#here i want to call the base class fun()
```

Comment: While possible, that sounds like a terrible idea that's going to lead to terrible spaghetti code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input:

```
objb = b()
super(b, objb).fun()
```

Output:

```
fun in base class
```

**Edit:**

As mentionned in comment below, in Python 2.7+ you need to declare `class a(object)` for this to work. This comes from a historical evolution of classes in Python, with this solution being functional for "new-style" classes only, i.e. for classes inheriting from `object`. In Python 3.x however, all classes are "new-style" by default, meaning you don't have to perform this small addition.

Comment: that is working only when i declare the base class as
"class a(object):"  but it doesnt work when i declare the base class as above. what is the reason for that .

Comment: @PranaySaraiwala - which you always should for a myriad of different reasons (in Python 3.x it's the default anyway). Old-style classes require explicit calls instead of using `super()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to call the 'base' function that works on old-style classes (classes that don't extend `object`) you can do it like:

```
objb = b()
a.fun(objb)  # fun in base class
```

Or if you don't know the base/parent class, you can 'extract' it from the instance itself:

```
objb = b()
objb.__class__.__bases__[0].fun(objb)  # fun in base class
```

But save yourself some trouble and just extend your base classes from `object` so you can use the `super()` notation instead of doing *bases* acrobatics.